# Is it possible to use Firebase Authentication to update OAuth interaction in native applications?

Tags: google-oauth, firebase-authentication

Currently our app uses OAuth requests in web-views.
Google will not allow OAuth requests in an embedded browser called "web-views".[google_developer_blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)
So, we are planning to use Firebase Authentication.
This method is not in best practice, but I would like to tell you if there is any problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google OAuth plans to deprecate embedded webviews. However, you are OK to use SFSafariViewController for iOS apps and Chrome Custom Tab for Android Apps. If none of these are supported, you can open a system browser. All of these flows are allowed for OAuth flows and are more secure than embedded webviews.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Our App is not using SFSafariViewController and Chrome Custom Tab.
And we know that we can authenticate with the system browser.
However, we want to use firebase.
Just a good opportunity, I thought that I could use Firebase Authentication for this OAuth flows.
Is it wrong to use firebase?

Comment: Firebase on native applications does not handle the OAuth flow for you. You have to use the Identity provider native SDK (Google, Facebook, Twitter) to retrieve the OAuth credential and then pass it to Firebase. In the case of GitHub, which doesn't have a native SDK, you have to get the GitHub access token on your own via a traditional OAuth2.0 flow.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.
We will follow the best practices and use the recommended SDK to retrieve the OAuth credential.